# Sharepoint CSOM and ensure user

Tags: client-object-model

I'm converting a console app into a WCF service and have hit a minor snag.

since there are more than 2500+ records to process and for each record I need to ensure the user initials in the list, loading the user through ensure user and the executing the query each time will definitely take a long time .

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Are users are different in each list.

Comment: yes, each list item corresponds to a user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first query the list with distinct users in the list and create/ensure that users.

So you don't need to query for every listitem.